# Searchable collapsible tree using D3.js in google sheet

Tags: html, d3.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, tree

Can someone explain how I can reproduce the example in http://bl.ocks.org/colinyzhao/6262093 to have a searchable collapsible tree embeded in google sheet.
The example shows 2 parts, an html code (index.html) and a json structure (insurance.json). I have saved the html in the script and I have saved the json code as a json file in Drive and it doesn't work and wondering if someone knows how I can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use D3.js on the Google Spreadsheet.

  - The sample of D3.js is http://bl.ocks.org/colinyzhao/6262093
  - From this, I thought that you want to put it to the dialog of Google Spreadsheet.

### Important point:

In order to use the JSON object as the data instead of the file, it is required to modify as follows.

#### From

```
d3.json("insurance.json", function(error, flare) {
      root = flare;
      root.x0 = h / 2;
      root.y0 = 30;
      root.marker = "i00";

      function collapse(d, index) {
        d.parent = this;
        d.marker = this.marker + generateMarker(index);
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse, d);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

      root.children.forEach(collapse, root);
      update(root);
    });
```

#### To:

```
root = flare;
root.x0 = h / 2;
root.y0 = 30;
root.marker = "i00";

function collapse(d, index) {
  d.parent = this;
  d.marker = this.marker + generateMarker(index);
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse, d);
    d.children = null;
  }
}

root.children.forEach(collapse, root);
update(root);
```

- In this case, `flare` is the JSON object.

When above point is reflected to a sample script for Google Apps Script and HTML, it becomes as follows.

### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following scripts to the script editor of the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet.

#### Google Apps Script side: `Code.gs`

```
function myFunction() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setWidth(1000).setHeight(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample title");
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side: `index.html`

In this case, the script is large. So I put it to jsfiddle.net. Please copy and paste the script from https://jsfiddle.net/05phgbL6/ to `index.html` in the script editor.

- When you run the function of `myFunction` at the script editor, the dialog is opened to the Spreadsheet.
- You can also use the sidebar.

### Note:

- If you want to separate the HTML and JSON as 2 files, please do the following flow.

  1. Put the HTML and Javascript of http://bl.ocks.org/colinyzhao/6262093 to `index.html` in the script editor.
  2. Put the JSON data of http://bl.ocks.org/colinyzhao/6262093 to `json.html` in the script editor.
  3. Put `<?!= include("json") ?>` after `<div id="tree"></div>` of the HTML and Javascript.
  4. Modify the Google Apps Script as follows.

     ```
      function myFunction() {
        const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate().setWidth(1000).setHeight(1000);
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample title");
      }

      function include(filename) {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
      }
     ```
  5. Run the function of `myFunction`. By this, the JSON data is put to the HTML and Javascript.

### References:

- [Class Ui](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)
- [Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)